# Find similar words in a string

Tags: php, regex

I am trying to fetch similar words in a string. Suppose I have got a set of 5 keywords.

cats, dogs, animals, food, water

And I have a string like this

"Cat's an animal but different from a dog. Food's not same for both of them. But they both drink water."

If I try to use strpos in this case, I may find only one similar word "water" but in fact there are others too. What can help me achieve to detect all keywords in the sentence mentioned above?

Comment: What is your expected output? Can you show your attempted code?

Comment: Could you paste your existing code? It is difficult to see what your problem is without seeing how youre trying to accomplish this. It could be a case insensitive issue, or perhaps an issue with the arguments passed to `strpos()`.

Answer (score 0):

Its possible you have an issue with case sensitivity. Try using the `stripos()` [function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.stripos.php). It could also be an issue with pluralization, or contractions, in which case [a regular expression](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match-all.php) might make this easier.

Answer (score 0):

For using regex -
This might mitigate contractions and boundary punctuation and such.
A more elaborate technique would be needed if detecting similarities
down to the character level.

`(?i)(?<!\S)(?:cat(?:'?s)?|dog(?:'?s)?|animal(?:'?s)?|food|water)(?:(?=\p{P})|(?!\S))`

Formatted:

```
 (?i)
 (?<! \S )
 (?:
      cat
      (?: '?s )?
   |  dog
      (?: '?s )?
   |  animal
      (?: '?s )?
   |  food
   |  water
 )
 (?:
      (?= \p{P} )
   |  (?! \S )
 )
```